# Guava Cache: concurrent values not added to cache

Tags: java, guava

So, this method is called when the request comes in and I save the data to cache. Requests can be concurrent. 
However, after, lets say, 10 requests, I expect the cache size to be 10, but the size is 1 with the 10th request data.

I'm missing something simple here, but can't figure out.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RequestCacheService {

    private ReadWriteLock lock;

    RequestCacheService() {
        lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public void saveToCache(RequestDto requestDto) {
        log.info("Saving request");
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();

            cache.build();
            cache.getRequiredCache()
                    .put(requestDto.getTimestamp().getEpochSecond(), requestDto.getData());
            log.info("Size of cache: " + cache.getRequiredCache().size());
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
```

This is the CacheService:

```
public class CacheService {
    private static LoadingCache<Long, String> REQUIRED_CACHE;


    public static LoadingCache<Long, String> getRequiredCache() {
        return REQUIRED_CACHE;
    }

    public static void build() {
        REQUIRED_CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<Long, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String load(Long s) throws Exception {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are recreating the cache on every call (`cache.build`)

Comment: Yes, because I need to set expire for each key. I’m not sure if that’s the correct the way to do it.

Comment: The cache should be built once. In that setting, each entry has a 30s lifetime after a write. If you interested 1 per second, after a minute half would have expired.

Comment: Initially I kept the variable expireAfter, which I added as first argument to expireAfterWrite, and was decided basis on the key value. 
I have a use-case where I need to set different expire time for different key. I'm not sure if that would be possible if the cache is built just once.

Comment: That isn't supported by Guava's cache. [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based), the successor, does offer support.

Comment: Can I use the same approach I'm using here? or do I have to use expireAfter(new Expiry<>{}) ? for my specific case

Comment: You have to use `expireAfter` and should only build the cache once.

Comment: And if I don't want to use expireAfterRead and expireAfterUpdate?

Comment: That's fine, just return `currentDuration` in those cases to have no effect.

Comment: And I still don't understand, how can I have different expiry if I build just once? :/ Sorry, just confused a little

Comment: The cache evaluates the entry by calling the `Expiry` during `cache.put` to calculate the lifetime. That duration is used to place the entry in a sorted order on an internal data structure, so that when it expires the cache can evict it.

Comment: That would only happen if I use either key or value to get the expiry time, right?

Comment: Yes, usually a custom time per-entry is because the duration is determined by an external resource and is an attribute of the value. Otherwise you often use a fixed duration, e.g. 30 seconds, after which that individual entry expires.

Comment: And just to be sure, 
`long diff = currentTimeSecond - o1.longValue();
return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(diff); `
is this the correct usage? I'm expecting `diff` to be between 0-60.

Comment: That's probably a negative value if `o1` is the time when it expires. It otherwise makes sense, though of course test.